# Adding element to existing XML file with LINQ in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

On load my program executes the following code to establish if an XML file already exists, and if not, creates one:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If IO.File.Exists("Dictionary.xml") = False Then

        Dim Dictionary As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                                      <Root></Root>

            MessageBox.Show("XML dictionary file created.")
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm then trying to get user input from 4 textboxes to be appended to this xml file for each word. I've got so far, but can't find a good example of how to do this.

```
    Private Sub Save_Data_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Save_Data.Click

    Dim Dictionary As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Dictionary.xml")
    Dictionary.Add
    <Word>
        <English>Textbox1.Text</English>
        <Transcription>Textbox2.Text</Transcription>
        <Meaning>Textbox3.Text</Meaning>
        <Sound>Textbox4.Text</Sound>
    </Word>

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary.Root.Add( _
    New XElement("Word",Textbox1.Text, _
        New XElement("English",Textbox1.Text), _
        New XElement("Transcription",Textbox2.Text), _ 
        New XElement("Meaning",Textbox3.Text), _ 
        New XElement("Sound",Textbox4.Text))
```